# impacts on splitting web application (java) for reducing memory & compute footprint on primary user-facing app

Tags: java, architectural-patterns

TLDR;

what if you are tasked with taking out a feature and making it  app 2 to reduce memory/compute foot print from app 1? Making an API contract between app 1 & 2 would defeat the purpose because APIs run on app 1.

How then could we split a feature from a monolith that relies on the same data of app 1?

---

I need to review our architecture and wonder if any of you want to give it a go, I would appreciate learning from the insights.

We have a main spring java web app - Central. We had an export feature that exported our data via a background job. As the export component began to have more features added to it - send live events instead of daily exports etc, our architect decided to make it a separate app called integration(ims). His motivation? If the feature is separate, it can scale and not increase load (JVM) of Central as Central is user-facing and IMS is used for all kinds of requests from clients (exports, events etc). On paper, sounds nice. Here are the concerns below.

so IMS now queries Central because it needs data to export. All those queries were already present in Central, but they had to be copied and pasted - along with utils, ORM Entity classes - et al.

I shared with my product owner that IMS directly querying Central database as opposed to using API contracts - is an anti-pattern because any change in Central database is unknown to IMS app. If the contract is done via API and not queries, any change in DB structure is invisible to the API and would work for Central and IMS. My boss agreed. However, wasn't the whole idea of splitting the app because we didn't want to increase load on Central? Making API contracts between IMS and Central would be back to square one (as those APIs would run on Central)

Apart from DB changes, the other issue I am finding is the repition of code. As IMS needs to query Central for everything, it requires the same kind of service classes, utils, security improvements, S3 implemetations etc. So we're having a

problem no. 2: "have you remembered to make this change on IMS too?" - i.e Inablility to share code

We're not the first ones to split an app to reduce JVM load. And IMS is merely querying (read-only) Central. How do other teams tackle DB change impacts on shared java apps & inability to share util, classes etc? Or what have we done wrong and what could we have done better?

I don't think this question is limited to Java, its  an architectural design questions that applies to all technologies.

The split has already occured, so any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I'd probably opt for an own data layer in that case which can be used by both. Here you could partition the db-layer further with replicas i.e. to divide concerns further. The current master would then receive all writes while any replica is only used for read operations. If you look at microservice architecture in particular then data duplication isn't a big deal there. It is more important that the respective applications are master of their own data and know how to get data they need. In term of traceability most DB provide a log feature of some form

Comment: When you say "data layer" do you mean a separate web app or a jar? Can you share any reference ? I can't find any one doing something similar

Comment: Depending on your environment you can either directly expose the DB as data layer to your applications or create simple Spring backend applications that are able to use various technologies (i.e. Web API, Redis or the like) to exchange data with other applications. Such applications can be scaled to multiple instances or containers easily usually. It fully depends on which architecture model you prefer. I.e. with microservices you try to keep the db with the data of that service as close to the application as possible and thus usually deploy the DB to the same container the app is running in

Comment: @veritas I don't see any problems as long as both cheap API calls and long DB queries are used in the IMS. Please clarify why you think they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Security concerns are irrelevant as IMS is not an user-facing service. Service classes are not shared, because most will not be needed in the new service. In other words all of @veritas concerns are easily dispelled. The talk to product owner was an error.

Comment: @Basilevs both Central and IMS call the same database, hence they are mapped to the same Domain Entity POJO (ORM) POJO, service layers (pick this data first, then this i.e business logic)

I have just dropped a column on the Central Database and IMS had no clue about it and its native queries/JPA etc failed. So not sure what you are talking about when you say the talk with PO was futile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Central has interactive
[OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing)
latency requirements,
while IMS has batch reporting throughput requirements.
And you want them served from different containers,
to alleviate observed resource shortages.

Pursue these two improvements in parallel:

1. Replicate your database so writes go to a leader and are then propagated to follower(s). Now you have more read bandwidth available for readonly reporting tasks.
2. Write a common data layer library which both Central and IMS use to make database queries. If for example we delete a column, we update the data library to know about it. If it turns out to be a breaking change, javac will tell us about callers that depended on that column as part of the signature they used.

Now you can deploy M instances of Central,
each hitting the database leader node,
plus N instances of IMS which can directly query
as many as N near-realtime readonly database replicas.
And the people did rejoice.

Comment: how do I make a common data layer? use a common jar for both Central & IMS? I'm afraid I dont know how a common data layer looks like. Are there any references you can share?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Author a common .jar that both Central & IMS will both `import`. The data layer makes database / spring calls, while Central & IMS lack such imports, they only call routines in this new layer. Start small -- invent a brand new table which the three modules access directly or indirectly. Be sure to use JUnit to write an automated integration test. Once you have that working, follow the pattern to convert existing table access.

Comment: The common jar (data layer that has ORM classes and perhaps JPA API) solves issue of losing visibility on IMS due to change on Central. The concern left unaddressed is that if the two apps were supposed to be independent, their deyployments now seem coupled i.e whenever a column is dropped on Central and if Central (app + common Central DB) goes live, though the changes are visible to IMS, IMS would still break because those changes have not gone live on IMS even if they are available on git pull. That is, this is great for CI but does not address CD (continuous deployment). Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, when dropping a column there is definitely coupling ("versionitis") among {DB, data_layer, Central, IMS}. It is a good goal to allow deploying new DB in week 1, new data_layer in week 2, new Central in week 3, and new IMS in week 4. To accomplish that, you need to version the database, perhaps at granularity of "whole database". Personally, I tend to do it at table level, and I will "fix it with a VIEW". That is, version 1 of data layer uses SELECT x, y, z FROM foo_v1. Construct a projection that drops column Z with: CREATE VIEW foo_v2 AS SELECT x, y FROM foo_v1. Now "SELECT *" works.

Comment: versioning the database assumes that the read-only instance of Central IMS is calling is static. The read-only central DB is an AWS managed replica so structure changes will be instantly passed (thereby breaking IMS that is unbeknowst to the changes). So week1-week4 strategy is not going to work.

Comment: During week 2, data_layer "knows" about the new v2 schema, but no one calls data_layer_v2 routines. During week 3, Central _is_ calling those routines, so it accesses only the v2 schema, and is out-of-sync with ancient IMS. Not until week 4 do we rev. IMS to use the v2 routines, and at that point IMS learns of the disappearance of column Z. Think of each component as holding a [ref count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Garbage_collection) on v1 or v2 DB objects. When v1 ref count goes to zero in week 4, we may GC the old object. That is, DROP VIEW, followed by RENAME TABLE.

Comment: I see what you mean. versioning is the only way out here. The issue with the above design is that we export data out to clients. So if some old column has been redone or new column added and IMS receives an event from Central saying "someone added new data on Central, please pass it to client", IMS can't be sending some stale column for the delta time (a week or few days etc) because our versioning hasn't kicked in yet. So it can get complex to implement the above.

Comment: Often, I find I'm able to get away with "CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT x, y FROM foo_v2", and then many DB clients that directly issue SELECT queries can largely ignore the `_vN` suffixes. They can pretend there's no versioning, since they don't care, they happen to not be affected by the details. But in your case, it sounds like external clients _need_ to know about the metadata, they must be advised when we rev from schema v1 to v2. Simplest way to accomplish that is to expose that version suffix in .CSV filenames, RDBMS table names, API endpoints, and so on.

Comment: thank you for your insights. appreciated.